# Help with WPF Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I need to bind the custom dependency property to the Image elements inside a control.

Now the `Label`'s `Foreground` binds very well to `TextForeground`, but not the `GeometryDrawing` inside the `Image` (the Image remains Transparent).

What is wrong?

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyStopControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="12" Width="24">
    <Canvas >
        <Image x:Name="Dot" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
            <Image.Source>
                <DrawingImage>
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},Path=TextForeground}" Thickness="2" x:Name="BigCircleThickness"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <EllipseGeometry x:Name="BigCircle" Center="0,0" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7"/>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},Path=TextForeground}"  Thickness="1"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <EllipseGeometry x:Name="MediumCircle" Center="0,0" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4"/>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},Path=TextForeground}">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <EllipseGeometry x:Name="SmallCircle" Center="0,0" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>

        <Border x:Name="StopShadow"
                Background="{Binding ElementName=TextBackground}" 
                LayoutTransform="{Binding ElementName=StopText, Path=LayoutTransform}">
            <Label x:Name="StopLabel" 
                   Content="Bla bla some text" 
                   Foreground="{Binding ElementName=TextForeground}" />
        </Border>

    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GeometryDrawing` does not have a `TextForeground` property. You are referencing Self, which would be the `GeometryDrawing`. Change your `RelativeSource` if you are trying to grab the `TextForeground` from a different Control.

```
<GeometryDrawing.Pen>
    <Pen Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=TextForeground}" Thickness="1"/>
</GeometryDrawing.Pen>
```

Comment: **MyStopControl has** the `TextForeground` property. So by e.g. for the Label > `Foreground="{Binding ElementName=TextForeground}"` works wery well.

Comment: @serhio You are referencing RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self} on the GeometryDrawing though...in the Label you are not

Comment: so how should I change the Source in order to point to the usercontrol itself?

Comment: found also an other variant (that I used, by the way) thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyStopControl" >
    ...
    <Pen Brush="{Binding ElementName=MyStopControl, Path=TextForeground}"/>
    ...
</UserControl>
```